# Can't install using PIP - help fixing it?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am trying to install pygubu on a different device than I usually use. I have installed PIP but somewhere (recently) I somehow broke PIP. When I type `pip install pygubu` I get the messages:

```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pygubu    Cannot fetch index base URL
> http://pypi.python.org/simple/    Could not find any downloads that
> satisfy the requirement pygubu No distributions at all found for
> pygubu Storing complete log in
> C:\Users\PNX\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Can someone help me fix PIP? I know that it is broken due to me being able to install pygubu on another device.

Comment: What version of Python are you using in both the devices? Are they both the same?

Comment: it seems that there is  no internet on that device. PIP has to download the package before installing it

Comment: @БогданОпир, that may not be the issue because he might have got the error message saying something like: "failed to establish connection", if his device wasn't connected to the internet

Comment: Can someone tell me why my question has been downvoted? I need to ask another but I can't due to getting low scores on other questions :( - also @phd I will change the image to text as per your request. 

Comment: I retracted my vote.

Comment: @PNX, I downvoted. It seems to me the problem you encountered -although real- is not worth a question on this website. In the sense that I am pretty sure there are similar answered questions already and also it doesn't really add much value to the site. On the other hand I couldn't find a similar question with a satisfying answer. Anyway I change my vote as it obviously doesn't deserve being blocked from asking further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

1) Go to this link: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py , copy the code and save it as `get-pip.py`

2) Navigate to the directory that you saved `get-pip.py` at, using CMD

3) Then type this command on CMD: `python get-pip.py`

4) pip should be successfully installed after this.

If this doesn't work, try uninstalling pip by using: `python -m pip uninstall pip`, and try the above process again.

By the way, you might be actually facing this issue because you might be using a very old version of pip, and installing the latest version might solve your problem.

So another thing you could do is to upgrade pip by using the override prefix like this in your upgrade command: `pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip`

**PS: Make sure that you are not using a proxy, and if you are, then use your proxy settings with the commands.**

Comment: Thanks Your 'pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip' in cmd worked! I have now installed what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! @PNX :)